# Azure DevOps Work Item Extension - Save() Error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have a simple Work Item Extension that updates a custom field on my Work Item.

When I run the below code the very first time onload, it Saves successfully and correctly updates. However, the second time I Save() I receive the following exception. I have confirmed that the second Save does indeed change the Custom Fields.

```
"Error: Work item can not be saved in its current state. Its either not changed or has errors.
    at W.beginSaveWorkItem (https://cdn.vsassets.io/ext/ms.vss-work-web/new-work-item-form-extension/ms.vss-work-web.new-work-item-form-extension.es6.OcLecr.min.js:1:10465)"
```

However, when I force reload the page, the custom field IS getting updated and all is working.

```
   WorkItemServices.WorkItemFormService.getService().then(function (service) {

                    // once both fields are updated, save the work item
                    Promise.all([
                        service.setFieldValue("Custom.Field1", Field1Val),
                        service.setFieldValue("Custom.Field2", Field2Val)
                    ]).then(value => {

                        service.isDirty().then(val => {

                            console.log(val);
                        });
    
                        service.save().then(value => {

                            // the first time a Save() happens, this callback is never hit. however the second time it does get hit, and includes the mentioned exception.
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly with regards to programmatically Saving the Work Item?